# In Ruby on Rails, how to solve User must have Address and Address must have User so they can't validate when saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

For example, if the validation says a User must have an address (we separate address from the users table, if we allow 1 user to have as many addresses as needed associated with one user).
At the same time, the address must have a user (must belong to a user).  So there is a `user_id` that points back to which user it is.

Then when you save the user or save the address, you can't because if you save a new user first, it can't point a valid address, but
if you save the address first, the user hasn't been saved -- so there is no id for a user record.

In such case, how do you handle it -- and is it the same in Rails 2.2 or 2.3 or 3.0?  thanks.

Comment: Are you using a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship? Or has_many through?

Comment: for now I am using for the User Model: `has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy` and for the Address Model, `belongs_to :user` (is using Rails 2.2.2)

Comment: I think you need to fix your associations a little better.. For example, what will happen if you have 2 users that live at the same address and then you delete 1 of your users?

Comment: aha... good point.  the example I use is `address`... but in reality it is `identity`... for logging into the system if a user can log in through Facebook, Twitter, Gmail, and any OpenID.  It is done through a mechanism by JanRain (RPX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure this will work but try something like this, using your original example.

```
@user = User.new

@user.build_address( pass params in here)

@user.save!
```

and vice versa..